# Export contents of Iframe

Tags: iframe, dynamics-crm

I’ve an Iframe inside a Dynamics CRM form. This Iframe displays content from an external site and the users need to be able to export (save) the contents of the iframe to be used when they go offline.

Any ideas on how to achieve?

Comment: does that external site have an export feature?  If so, you would need to leverage that.  If the page is just framed in, CRM has no concept of actually storing that data, so it would not be able to export data that it doesn't know about.

Comment: I think you would need s proxy solution if you want to achieve this cross site loading and downloading..

Comment: what do you mean by proxy solution, luca?